# ASP MVC WriteLiteral("\r\n"); Unrecognized escape sequence error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

my asp MVC Projects Builds successfully but when i try to run any view i am getting  Unrecognized escape sequence error and Error Describes `WriteLiteral("\r\n");`

```
Source File: c:\Users\Mohamed\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\1bc13a3b\8a6f90dd\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.teskwqdt.0.cs    Line: 1194
```

I have no Idea where this line is written WriteLiteral("\r\n");

Comment: Looks like the error is occurring inside one of your view (cshtml) files. You would have to figure out which one and where.

Comment: @Igor 2  how i could know the View ; i've searched the above line in all files of the project but cant find where

Comment: `\r\n` (CR-LF/carriage return with newline or `0x000D000A`) are character literals which often used in Windows to mark empty line. Check `App_Web_index.cshtml` file for possible unexpected empty lines, or use `@` to mark the string as literal one if exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the problem and solved it.

while i was trying to remove Extra Javascript code lines added by a virus to all my views with Find & Replace   i left a whitespace-like character after this line;

And Finally Removing Those Characters From all views Manually Solved the Problem !